# How to split apk for several CPU architectures?

Tags: android, bundle, android-app-bundle

I develop an application that released in Google Play.
I got a letter from Google that my app must be apt to new requirements for 64bit devices (https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit)

My app used ffmpeg library that not provided build for 64 architecture: https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java

Apk analyze with this library was looked like that:
[image]

As you can see there are only 32-bit architectures presented.

So, I replaced old FFmpeg library with new one: https://github.com/bravobit/FFmpeg-Android
Also I added a line to my app `build.gradle` file:

```
  ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
```

Then I assembled new apk file and analyzed it. There is result:
[image]

**Question 1:** Is `arm` directory means directory for 64-bit systems?

**Question 2:** Where is gone directory `libs` from prev screenshot? Is it normal?

That's not all. As you can see, APK size increased by 20 Mb. It's very bad, so I decided to apply App Bundle mechanism to my application.
I added several lines to my app's `build.gradle` file more:

```
    bundle {
        density {
            enableSplit = true
        }
        abi {
            enableSplit = true
        }
    }
```

And assembled a Bundle then. After it I expect a Bundle with apk files, divided by density and abi architectures. But I get only Bundle with only density division, there are no different apk for different CPU's:

[image]

**Question 3:** why my bundle doesn't contain apk's divided by CPU architectures? All density-divided apks are containing libs for both architectures (arm and armeabi)